# Using Future and Async to handle multiple file IO requests without blocking

Tags: scala, file, file-io, future, nonblocking

I'm new to scala and exploring how to write non-blocking IO code for reading from a file.
Following is the method that reads from the cache file and returns the JSON output to the API endpoint.

```
def retrieveCache = {
    val source = Source.fromFile(fileName)
    val content = try source.mkString
    finally source.close()

    // Some Parsing JSON Code...
    
    // At the end, clearing the cache from the file
    fileName.writeAll("")
}
```

I read about using Future and Async to achieve non-blocking IO and did try a couple of things. But not exactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, to convert blocking code to asynchronous `Future`-based code, you just

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
```

and then wrap code using `Future.apply`:

```
val fut = Future {
  // insert code here
}
```

`Future.apply` will run the block using an implicit `ExecutionContext` (basically an abstraction of a threadpool, though in the case of ScalaJS (and Scala Native, at least for now) it's more of an event-loop).  If there's no implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope, you'll have to specify one.  The compiler will suggest to

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global  // a.k.a. "the implicit global ExecutionContext"
```

For CPU-bound operations, the implicit global context is perfectly fine, but for performing blocking I/O operations, it's rather suboptimal: the threads in that context will generally be blocked and that context only has as many threads as the JVM detects cores.  The solutions to this are either to: use `blocking` to mark the portion of code which is blocking (this potentially allows the blocking to happen on another thread), or define an `ExecutionContext` with more threads for doing blocking I/O but not for doing computation.

To use `blocking`, which is often all that you need:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future, blocking }

// Be careful about blindly importing this...
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def retrieveCache = Future {
  val content = blocking {
    val source = Source.fromFile(fileName)
    try {
      source.mkString
    } finally source.close()
  }

  // Parse the JSON

  blocking {
    fileName.writeAll("")
  }
}
```

In my experience the sugar which `async` provides isn't that much of a benefit: I much prefer just working with `Future` composition.